# Is there a clearer alternative to COB when you work for a global company?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrases, abbreviations, business-language

The company that I work for is literally global hence it could truly be said is **never** closed for business, (some sections even function on Christmas Day, either because of regional observances or because the work cannot be interrupted).  Likewise operations such as the health services and other emergency services have no true Close of Business.

But you still hear, or see in e-mails, things like *"I need this report by **COB** today".*

I am wondering if anybody knows of a clear unambiguous word, phrase or abbreviation for what such writers really mean, i.e. before the end of normal office hours at this location, who knows maybe if I can find something I can, by example, get everybody to use it.

Comment: Just get them to use an actual time. Clear and unambiguous, and could even be before the last person leaves the office.

Comment: Our site alone uses both flexi-time for some workers and shift covering 24/7 fpr others. I wish that people would use an actual time but...

Answer (score 1):

I believe this is context-sensitive and if used unqualified, it should mean the COB at the location of the deliverable.

Else, the (less ambiguous) alternatives are:

> COB **so-and-so**(timezone) : COB Utopia Time
>
> **so-and-so**(exact time) **so-and-so**(timezone): 5:30 pm Utopia Time

Wiktionary:

> *Noun*
> **[COB](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/COB)** ‎(plural COBs)
>
> Close of Business, usually referring to a deadline for an office in
> another time zone.
>
> NY office told the LA office to have report e-mailed by COB.

Comment: I often don't know which timezone co-workers are in a the time of writing it is not unusual for the guy that normally sits 3 desks from me to be emailing from 11/12 timezones away.

Comment: I guess you'll then have to have _your_ timezone as reference and qualify _COB_ (or explicit time) accordingly. The other person obviously needs to take care of the math.

Comment: Hence I am looking for something less ambiguous.

Comment: Just curious, why do you rule out `COB XYZ Time` as _the phrase_ where `XYZ` is _your_ timezone? Is it not unambiguous?

Comment: Because COB Today GMT could be "end of core hours", "end of my/your shift", midnight, "my/your going home time" and still depends on what the local working pattern at the speakers location is, i.e. expected working hours differ from location to location and business to business. I cannot expect someone in another part of the world to know when we normally finish work even if I tell them what timezone I am in.

Comment: Since you can't remove the time zone problem, and you've now introduced the terminology problem, what would be wrong with stating the actual time?

How could 5:30om XYZ Time or 17:30ABC Time be ambiguous?